# Add class with setTimeout without Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

Is it possible to convert this jquery script to non-jquery script?

```
window.setTimeout(function(){$("#fullcontent").addClass("onload");}, 2100);
```

I would like to add `class` "onload" to the `div` called "fullcontent" with `setTimeout` of 2,1s.

Answer (score 3):

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
  document.querySelector('#fullcontent').className = "onload";
}, 2100);
```

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LGMKOJ

Edit: In case you don't want to overwrite the element's current class:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
  var element = document.querySelector('#fullcontent');
  var className = element.className;
  element.className = className.concat(" onload");
}, 2100);
```

Comment: A temporary variable and .concat()? Wouldn't the += operator be simpler?

Comment: Thank you very much ! that does that work, I cannot vote up your comment, but this is what helped me :)

Comment: No problem! Don't worry about the upvote, I think you can accept it though

Answer (score 0):

Use of `.querySelector()` and `.concat()` are unnecessary and slower than the alternatives (GEBI and `+=`).

If you're sure that `#fullcontent` does not already have the class "onload", this will work fine:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("fullcontent").className += " onload";
}, 2100);
```

The safer, cleaner way to avoid duplicate classes if `#fullcontent` may have already been given the "onload" class:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var fullcontent = document.getElementById("fullcontent");

    if(fullcontent.className.indexOf("onload") === -1) {
        fullcontent.className += " onload";
    }
}, 2100);
```

If `#fullcontent` has no class whatsoever, you don't need to append and you can simply overwrite:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("fullcontent").className = "onload";
}, 2100);
```